# Mixed ANOVA, all Sigs = .000?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, p-value, variable

I made sure everything was done correctly, why would Mixed Anova results in a P value = .000 in all tables, please?

Comment: It could be all those p-values are small and your software rounds to 3 decimal places. But this is just speculation because I don't know what software you are using and what your output looks like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we *assume* that everything was done correctly, then you can conclude that all the p values were less than 0.0005 and that your software rounds to 3 digits. But assuming things like that is dangerous.

Why might all the p values be very low?  The two primary reasons are that you have really strong effects or really large N.  Since you  didn't tell us anything about  your data set, your variables, your model, your sample size, your sampling plan or anything else, it's impossible for us to say.

Comment: I had 148 participants in that data. Thank you very much for your all feedback